# Heats of combustion of pentadiene isomers

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons

This is a problem from the book Organic Chemistry by Carey and Giuliano (10th edition), the problem is:

> Match the heats of combustion with the compounds:
> The compounds are 1,3-pentadiene, 1,2-pentadiene and 1,4-pentadiene and the heats of combustion are given as 761.6 kJ/mol, 768.9 kJ/mol and 777.1 kJ/mol.

I know from my knowledge of organic chemistry that 1,3-pentadiene is the most stable of the three compounds (since its π bonds are in conjugation), therefore its heat of combustion corresponds to the minimum of the given heats of combustion, ie. 761.6 kJ/mol, however I am confused about how will I compare heats of combustion of 1,2-pentadiene and 1,4-pentadiene.

Comment: (1) Please don't use `$\text{...}$` for no reason; you really don't need to use, and shouldn't be using, MathJax unless you're writing equations. (2) Chemical names are not capitalised unless at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: I will take care of what you said the next time when I use chemistry SE

Comment: Your question isn't exactly the same as https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/110857/16683 (yours is better - that one is poorly formulated), but the answers there address your exact case.